# How to measure harddrive performance of a particular process in linux using perl script

Tags: perl

Below is the code I have tried,but only some entries are there. Here for example I have used chrome in the script. Is there another way to find the harddrive performance of particular process?

```
my @processes;
@processes=`iotop -b -n 1 | grep chrome`;
my $read_per_second=0;
my $write_per_second=0;
foreach(@processes)
{
    my $read=0;
    my $write=0;
    while ($_ =~ /([\d\.]+)\s+[B|K]\/s+\s+([\d\.]+)/sg)
    {
        $read_per_second+=$1;
        $write_per_second+=$2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given process you can get the current I/O statistics in `/proc/[pid]/io`.

If you read from this file multiple times you can get the reads and writes per second.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

for (1 .. 3) {

    my ($read_bytes_one, $write_bytes_one) = get_io_stats();

    open(my $fh, '>', '/tmp/foo');
    print $fh "x" x 1_000_000;
    close($fh);

    my ($read_bytes_two, $write_bytes_two) = get_io_stats();

    say "Read bytes: ", $read_bytes_two - $read_bytes_one;
    say "Write bytes: ", $write_bytes_two - $write_bytes_one;
    say "----------";
}


sub get_io_stats {

    open(my $fh_in, '<', "/proc/$$/io");

    my %data;
    while (my $line = readline($fh_in)) {
        if ($line =~ m{^ ( .+? ) : \s+ ( \d+ ) $}msx) {
            $data{$1} = $2;
        }
    }

    close($fh_in);

    return @data{'rchar', 'wchar'};
}
```

Which outputs:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ ./read_write.pl
Read bytes: 95
Write bytes: 1000000
----------
Read bytes: 103
Write bytes: 1000000
----------
Read bytes: 103
Write bytes: 1000000
```

To make it report information on a specific process by process ID, simply replace `$$` with another PID from the command line.

To get stats per second, simply sleep for a second between each read of `/proc/[pid]/io`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $PID = $ARGV[0] or die "Usage: $0 'pid'\n";

for (1 .. 3) {

    my ($read_bytes_one, $write_bytes_one) = get_io_stats();

    sleep 1;

    my ($read_bytes_two, $write_bytes_two) = get_io_stats();

    say "Read bytes: ", $read_bytes_two - $read_bytes_one;
    say "Write bytes: ", $write_bytes_two - $write_bytes_one;
    say "----------";
}


sub get_io_stats {

    open(my $fh_in, '<', "/proc/$PID/io");

    my %data;
    while (my $line = readline($fh_in)) {
        if ($line =~ m{^ ( .+? ) : \s+ ( \d+ ) $}msx) {
            $data{$1} = $2;
        }
    }

    close($fh_in);

    return @data{'rchar', 'wchar'};
}
```

Which works like so:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ ./read_write.pl 
Usage: ./read_write.pl 'pid'

alex@yuzu:~$ ./read_write.pl 1806
Read bytes: 0
Write bytes: 444141
----------
Read bytes: 0
Write bytes: 441639
----------
Read bytes: 0
Write bytes: 451647
----------
```